# glossaries package - How to change the name of the glossary

Tags: glossaries

I am using just one glossary in my document. I'd like to substitute its name "Glossary" with "List of Symbols".

I know I can create a new glossary and name it "List of Symbols" using

```
\newglossary{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of Symbols}
```

but this would force me to write `type=symbols` in every `\newglossaryentry`.

Is it possible to just change the name of the main (and sole) glossary or set `symbols` as the main glossary?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\printglossary[title={List of Symbols}]
```

Comment: That would be great if my glossary was printed like that... It's not. It's inside a weird list of stuff to the front matter and I cannot seem to acess it. Is there any other way to change the title? Maybe by renewing some command?

Answer (score 1):

I've had luck with this:

```
\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{List of Symbols}
```

[image: A Latex title saying "List of Symbols"]